# How to build multidimensional array in wasm?

Tags: webassembly

How can I build a multidimensional array in web assembly text format? 
I want to build matrix operation, like matrix multiplication.

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code.

Comment: (func (export "loop") 
       (local $i i32)
        (block $block
            (loop $continue   
                (f32.store8
                       (get_local $i)             
                       (f32.const 1.0)             
                )                              
                (set_local $i (i32.add (get_local $i)(i32.const 1)))
                (br_if $block (i32.ge_u (get_local $i)(i32.const 65533))) 
                (br $continue)
            )       
        )
    )

Answer (score 1):

The best place to store arrays within WebAssembly is linear memory. This is a continuous block of addressable memory that you can read and write to using load / store instructions. It is up to you to compute the required offset for reading / writing to your matrix.